# Is it possible two different variable with one route in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, url-routing

http://example.com/{variable_a}  > page_name_a.aspx

http://example.com/{variable_b}  > page_name_a.aspx

I would like to open urls like the upside. I already set one route without problem. But if i would like to open page like:

http://example.com/wireless-mouse > opening page using {variable_a} route (product)

http://example.com/voip-services > opening page using {variable_b} route (service)

**Button Click** event for variable_a:

```
protected void product_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LinkButton gtproduct = sender as LinkButton;
   RepeaterItem ritem = gtproduct.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
   if (ritem != null)
   {
     Response.RedirectToRoute("products", new{variable_a = "wireless-mouse"});
   }
}
```

**Button Click** event for variable_b:

```
protected void service_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LinkButton gtservice = sender as LinkButton;
   RepeaterItem ritem = gtservice.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
   if (ritem != null)
   {
     Response.RedirectToRoute("services", new{variable_b = "voip-services"});
   }
}
```

It always opens first route {variable_a}. So, i need to redirect to page route {variable_a} to product listing or page route {variable_b} to be services.

This is just an example i know that all the repater item will show same page with this example. Just trying to be done if it's possible.

Comment: Can you explain the reason for that decision? Why you can't use different routes with different paths something like `example.com/products/{a}` and `example.com/services/{b}`?

Comment: well, yes i understand that i can use like that. But i need to set two different things because i need it. I have been seen working website like that and i want to learn how it works. @Xordal